# Controlar desde Delphi el maximizado de otras App

Tags: delphi

Programo en Delphi 6. :-)
Desarrollé una aplicación que ocupa un sector de la pantalla (algo así como una barra de tareas en la parte inferior) y que se sitúa "siempre visible" (Stay-On-Top). 
Ocurre que las demás aplicaciones quedan "detrás" cuando maximizan su propia ventana. Entiendo que yo podría interceptar mensajes de Windows (WM_SIZE) para hacer que las aplicaciones maximizen su ventana a unas medidas espcíficas. Si es esto correcto, no sé cómo hacerlo.
Si alguien puede darme alguna pista estaré agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que he entendido, lo que necesitas es desde tu aplicación interceptar el cambio de tamaño de otras ventanas del sistema para adaptarlas a lo que necesitas.
A priori te desaconsejaría esto, pues puede tiene algunos inconvenientes.

1. No hay forma de capturar ese "evento" a nivel de todas las aplicaciones desde la tuya de forma fácil; Se me ocurre un **hook de sistema**, pero no es trivial.
2. Por otro lado no sabes qué aplicaciones se ejecutan en el sistema y su comportamiento (y cómo ha sido programadas). El cambiar las propiedades de la ventana desde la tuya puede provocar errores o fallos en la visualización según tus cambios.
3. Según lo que comentas, no sólo debes cambiar el tamaño **sino también el estado**. Si una ventana se axinmiza, tendrás que cambiar ese estado, restaurarla y modificar el tamaño, cosa que también te puede dar problemas (siguiendo la misma lógica del punto anterior).

Lo dicho, a priori la solución que planteas no parece la mejor.

Tal vez deberías revisar información de cómo crear una **DeskBand** o cómo convertir la tuya en una. En ese caso, estos problemas de tamaño de otras aplicaciones los tendrías solucionados.